# Ruby dynamic variable name

Tags: ruby

is there any way to create variables in Ruby with dynamic names?

I'm reading a file and when I find a string, generates a hash.

e.g.

```
file = File.new("games.log", "r")

file.lines do |l|
  l.split do |p|
    if p[1] == "InitGame"
      Game_# = Hash.new
    end
  end
end
```

How could I change # in Game_# to numbers (Game_1, Game_2, ...)

Comment: Where do the numbers come from?

Comment: A variable name with a capital letter is considered bad practice in Ruby unless you are declaring a class or module name. Consider changing `Game_` to `game_`.

Comment: What would you *do* with those dynamically-created names? Your source code couldn't refer to them except via clunky `send`s. Looks like an array to me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do it with instance variables like

```
i = 0
file.lines do |l|
  l.split do |p|
    if p[1] == "InitGame"
      instance_variable_set("@Game_#{i += 1}", Hash.new)
    end
  end
end
```

but you should use an array as viraptor says. Since you seem to have just a new hash as the value, it can be simply

```
i = 0
file.lines do |l|
  l.split do |p|
    if p[1] == "InitGame"
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
Games = Array.new(i){{}}
Games[0] # => {}
Games[1] # => {}
...
```

Comment: More info:  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get

Answer (score 9):

Why use separate variables? It seems like you just want `Game` to be a list with the values appended to it every time. Then you can reference them with `Game[0]`, `Game[1]`, ...

Answer (score 1):

If you really want dynamic variable names, may be you can use a Hash, than your can set the key dynamic

```
file = File.new("games.log", "r")
lines = {}
i = 0

file.lines do |l|
  l.split do |p|
    if p[1] == "InitGame"
      lines[:"Game_#{i}"] = Hash.new
      i = i + 1
    end
  end
end
```