# Iterating over an array to create variables in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, variables, variable-assignment

Is it possible to create multiple variables by iterating over an array?

For example, say I had an array called `numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]` and I wanted to create a series of variables called `number_1`, `number_2`,...,`number_5` each equal to their respective index in the numbers array (e.g. `number_1 = 1`, `number_2 = 2`, etc.).

I tried something along the lines of the following:

```
numbers.each_with_index do |num, index|
  number_"#{index+1}" = num
end
```

But that failed.

Essentially, I would like for the iterating process to automate creating and assigning values to variables.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What does `number_1` give you that `numbers[0]` doesn't?

Comment: This will probably meet your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16419767/2177

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is:

```
instance_variable_set("@number_#{index+1}", num)
```

Another way is using the `eval` method to create an instance variable:

```
eval "@number_#{index+1} = #{num}"
```

Heads up that `eval` is considered a bit hacky, and doesn't work on JRuby.

(Caveat: the code above creates instance variables, not scope-level variables (a.k.a. local variables). Example: the code creates `@number_1` not `number_1`. As far as I'm aware Ruby does not offer a straightforward way to dynamically create a scope-level variable that persists; you can create one within an `eval` but it goes out of scope beyond the `eval`.)

Comment: Note that this will not create local variables (as seems to have been requested). There is no way to create local variables in this way.