# How can I get a Ruby variable from a line read from a file?

Tags: ruby

I need to reuse a textfile that is filled with one-liners such:

```
export NODE_CODE="mio12"
```

How can I do that in my Ruby program the var is created and assign as it is in the text file?

Comment: Read the file and for each (matching) line create a variable and assign the value. (or maybe put them in a hash)

Comment: Maybe the question then is how can I create that var name and assign it into that value in dynamically?

Comment: Possibly worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419767/ruby-dynamic-variable-name And the right answer is probably a hash.

Comment: Is it bash executable script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file were a Ruby file, you could require it and be able to access the variables after that:

```
# variables.rb

VAR1 = "variable 1"
VAR2 = 2


# ruby.rb

require "variables"
puts VAR1
```

If you're not so lucky, you could read the file and then loop through the lines, looking for lines that match your criteria ([Rubular](https://rubular.com/) is great here) and making use of Ruby's `instance_variable_set` method. The `gsub` is to deal with extra quotes when the matcher grabs a variable set as a string.

```
# variables.txt

export VAR1="variable 1"
export VAR2=2


# ruby.rb

variable_line = Regexp.new('export\s(\w*)=(.*)')
File.readlines("variables.txt").each do |line|
  if match = variable_line.match(line)
    instance_variable_set("@#{match[1].downcase}", match[2].gsub("\"", ""))
  end
end
puts @var1
puts @var2
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the answer I was looking. Never heard about the method instance_variable_set

Answer (score 1):

Creating a hash from this file can be a fairly simple thing.

For `var.txt`:

```
export BLAH=42
export WOOBLE=67
```

```
File.readlines("var.txt").each_with_object({}) { |line, h| 
  h[$1] = $2 if line =~ /^ export \s+ (.+?) \s* \= \s* (.+) $/x
}
# => {"BLAH"=>"42", "WOOBLE"=>"67"}
```

Comment: I don't see the line within the loop that simple.

Comment: The regular expression looks for an export line, with the name and the value matched as `$1` and `$2`. If the regex matches, and entry is put into the hash.